# Huggingface tokenizer always encodes as unknown - Conversion of vocab.txt?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I have used [google's implementation of electra](https://github.com/google-research/electra) to train a model from scratch.
For the pretraining I have followed [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/pre-training-bert-from-scratch-with-cloud-tpu-6e2f71028379) -- with modifications of course, since it uses google's implementation for BERT. After having finished the training & also having converted the electra discriminator checkpoint to huggingface format using [this script](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/d5d7d886128732091e92afff7fcb3e094c71a7ec/src/transformers/convert_electra_original_tf_checkpoint_to_pytorch.py), I am trying to load the model in order to get the embeddings for some sentences.

First, I create the ElectraConfig, and then I create a tokenizer using the vocab.txt I have created (based on the aforementioned tutorial)

```py
config = ElectraConfig(vocab_size=100000,
                       embedding_size=768,
                       hidden_size=768,
                       num_hidden_layers=12,
                       num_attention_heads=4,
                       intermediate_size=3072,
                       hidden_act="gelu",
                       hidden_dropout_prob=0.1,
                       attention_probs_dropout_prob=0.1,
                       max_position_embeddings=512,
                       position_embedding_type="absolute")

tokenizer = ElectraTokenizer.from_pretrained(path_to_vocab)
```

My problem is that the tokenizer encodes all tokens in all sentences as unknown.
Do I need to convert the vocab.txt file? Is the creation of the vocab.txt file described in the tutorial incompatible with huggingface?

Comment: What is in the directory `path_to_vocab`? Can you upload your tokenizer files and share them with us (this will save us some time doing the tutorial by ourselves and guessing what you might have done)?